# Sencha Touch 2 and Ext.Direct API calling - Login Form

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

**So the main question is**: Does any one know how I need to change my calling method to be compatible with Sencha Touch 2?

**Description**:
I have a large Extjs application with a C# backend. I already have a mobile site with pages, but none of them require submitted form data. The trouble came when trying to create a login page.

On the desktop, using extjs and Ext.direct, there are login forms and they work fine, but the same coding patterns don't seem to work with Sencha Touch 2.

```
Ext.define('PF.view.phone.login.Form', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: 'widget.phoneloginform',
requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet', 'Ext.form.Password', 'Ext.Label', 'Ext.Img'],
autoheight: true,
initialize: function () {
    this.build();
    this.callParent();
    Ext.apply(this, {
        api: {
            submit: LoginActionImpl.login
        }
    });
    scope: this
},
config: {
    title: 'Login',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'Client Login',
            itemId: 'clientLoginLabel',
            style: 'text-align: left; font-size: 1.1em',
            margin: '10 0 20 0'
        }, {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            /*Temporary style*/
            margin: '10 17% 10 17% ',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    itemId: 'loginUsername',
                    name: 'loginUsername',
                    label: 'Username',
                    required: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    itemId: 'loginPassword',
                    name: 'loginPassword',
                    label: 'Password',
                    required: true
                }, {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    layout: {
                        pack: 'right'
                    },
                    ui: 'plain',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId: 'loginButton',
                        text: 'Login',
                        ui: 'confirm'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        itemId: 'clearButton',
                        text: 'Clear',
                        ui: 'decline'
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
   ]
},
build: function () {
    this.down('#clearButton').setHandler(this.clear);
    this.down('#loginButton').setHandler(this.login);
},
clear: function (btn, evt) {
    btn.up('phoneloginform').reset();

},
login: function (btn, evt) {
    /* Need help here */
    /* Below is what would normally be used in the rest of the application */
    this.submit({
        success: this.onLoginSuccess,
        failure: function (form, action) {
            this.onLoginFailure(action.result);
        },
        scope: this
    });
},
onLoginSuccess: function (arguments) {

    Ext.dispatch('login/success');
},
onLoginFailure: function (result) {

    // Here we need to check the actual results to determine why the login failed.
    //
    // A return code of -2 indicates account locked - otherwise we just assume an invalid attempt.
    //
    if (result.returnCode == -2) {
        this.getComponent("loginUsername").markInvalid(t('ptl_mbl_user_status_locked_password'));
        this.getComponent("loginUsername").markInvalid(t('ptl_mbl_user_status_locked_password'));
    }
    else {
        this.getComponent("loginUsername").markInvalid(t('wms_username_password_incorrect_error'));
        this.getComponent("loginPassword").markInvalid(t('wms_username_password_incorrect_error'));
    }
    Ext.dispatch('login/fail', result.returnCode);
},

getUsername: function () {
    if (this.username) {
        this.username = this.getValues()['#loginUsername'];
    }
},

getPassword: function () {
    if (this.password) {
        this.password = this.getValues()['#loginPassword'];
    }
}
});
```

The method of the C# method is:

```
    [DirectMethodForm]
    public JObject login(HttpRequest request)
    {
        String username = request["loginUsername"];
        String password = request["loginPassword"];
        this.setDB(request["db"]);

        int loginReturnCode = this.getUserDetailsService().login(username, password, this.getDB(), true);

        JObject jsonObject;
        if (loginReturnCode == 0)
        {
            jsonObject = new JObject(
                new JProperty("loginUsername", username),
                new JProperty("loginPassword", password),
                new JProperty("db", this.getDB()),
                new JProperty("success", true));
        }
        else
        {
            jsonObject = new JObject(
                new JProperty("errors", new JArray(new[] { loginReturnCode.ToString() })),
                new JProperty("returnCode", loginReturnCode),
                new JProperty("failed", true));
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

and what I'm trying to reuse so that can't be changed.

Stepping through the code in the browser, the issue comes during the "urlAppend" method in the "sencha-touch-all.js" file where the "url" parameter is null, so the call never reaches the C# code.

```
    urlAppend : function(url, string) {
    if (!Ext.isEmpty(string)) {
        return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + string;
    }

    return url;
},
```

However, I've never needed to set that variable before, in using Ext.direct. I don't have a separate web service, so actual web service calls are not available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Touch requires you to use the setters, you can't just apply properties directly on the class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eva. Sorry, I'm not sure which properties are you talking about? Did you mean username and password setters?

Comment: No, where you're calling `apply` on the class. You need to use the setter. Also, you have a random `scope: this` sitting in that method.

Comment: Found from Sencha Forums that Sencha Touch 2.2.x doesn't support submitting a form via Ext.Direct. It wasn't added until 2.3.0. Anyways, thanks for your reply!